# How to count row of input in python

Tags: python, list, row

I want to print out which row contains certain letter.

For example, if 0 is that certain letter,
when input is like

```
1111132323132323232313232
1323232313132323132323232
1232323201231323232313232
```

multiple lines input,

the output I expect is like 3. (Because 3rd row contains '0')

How can I get numberth row to be printed out?

Comment: you have 1d array or 2d array?

Comment: Please clarify, what the format of the input is.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work

```
a=[1111132323132323232313232,1323232313132323132323232,1232323201231323232313232]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if your_number in list(str(a[i])):
        print(i+1) # if you want 0 to n than i otherwise i+1
```

just use this concept for any dimensional array first convert into a list and check into that list.

Answer (score 0):

you need to [split](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/) string and  use 
 [in](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm) operator to find certain character in string.

or

you can also use [filter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-filter-python-examples/)

for example:

```
ip='''1111132323132323232313232 1323232313132323132323232  1232323201231323232313232'''
a=ip.split().index([x for x in ip.split() if '0' in x][0])
print (a+1)
```

`OR` with filter:

```
ip = '''1111132323132323232313232
        1323232313132323132323232 
        1232323201231323232313232''' 
strList=ip.split()
result = filter(lambda x: '0' in x ,strList)[0] 
print(strList.index(result)+1)
```